# Reset Exception, is there such a thing?

Tags: java, exception, jframe

If i am using a method to reset stuff such as a JTextField, could i throw an exception if it didn't work? Perhaps i don't need one at all?

e.g

```
private void resetJFrame()   
{  
 try
  {
 subtotalJTextField.setText( "" );   
 taxJTextField.setText( "" );  
  }
 catch
  {
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Why do you think you should throw an exception?

Comment: possibly typos, bugs perhaps. rather have a robust operation so its good practice to throw ones.

Comment: You're not throwing, you're catching. Why do you think it can fail anyway?

Comment: Ive explained already, yes catch an exception then

Comment: There are no exceptions to catch inside your try-block---except some unchecked exceptions like `NullPointerException`. There is no point in catching those; rather, you have to fix your code.

Comment: if it has typos, the compiler will catch them. If it has bugs, repair them. If you foresee an exception condition, then we can discuss that. Otherwise the exercise is pointless.

Comment: If i was to catch one, NullPointerException would be the one to use? i haven't added any to the code yet because i am unsure which one to use, if i need to or can use one at all. i wish people would read the question.

Comment: I believe you do not use exceptions to capture programming errors. A NullPointerException is, most likely, a programming error. As it would be IndexOutOfBoundExceptions, etc. Those things would represent bugs in a program and need to be fixed, not silently hidden by catching them.

Comment: You don't want to catch a NullPointerException, you want to fix your code so it isn't thrown in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method setText(), wont throw any exceptions.
If you want you can define your own exception and throw it using throw.(see http://www.java2novice.com/java_exception_handling_examples/create_custom_exception/ )

Not sure why you will want to do that..

Comment: Im not doing it, im asking if it can be done and if so, what could i do? but thanks